# Adding to numerous lists without code duplication Python

Tags: python

I retrieve data from the spotify api and try to put the audio features for the retrieved tracks into seperate lists.
I currently use the following code to make the request and retrieve the audio featurse :

```
query_get_tracks = f"https://api.spotify.com/v1/audio-features/?ids={','.join(ids)}"
tracks_response = requests.get(query_get_tracks, headers={
    "Authorization": f"Bearer {auth_token}"
}).json()['audio_features']
danceability_list, energy_list, key_list, loudness_list, mode_list, speechiness_list, 
acousticness_list, instrumentalness_list, liveness_list, valence_list, tempo_list, 
duration_ms_list = ([] for i in range(13))
for i in range(len(tracks_response)):
    base_items = tracks_response[i]
    danceability = base_items['danceability']
    energy = base_items['energy']
    key = base_items['key']
    loudness = base_items['loudness']
    mode = base_items['mode']
    speechiness = base_items['speechiness']
    acousticness = base_items['acousticness']
    instrumentalness = base_items['instrumentalness']
    liveness = base_items['liveness']
    valence = base_items['valence']
    tempo = base_items['tempo']
    duration_ms = base_items['duration_ms']
```

This seems like a lot of code duplication to me but I am not sure how to achieve the same functionality with less duplication. Note that the above code does not even append anything to the lists. How can I achieve my goal with less code duplication because the current solution is very ugly.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why can't you just use tracks_response[i][<Value>]? e.g when referring to loudness, instead of saving the parameter, just refer to tracks_response[I]['loudness']

Comment: Don't assign to new lists? You can just reference the different lists you created through the dict `tempo == tracks_response[i]['tempo']`. Anyway it is not clear what you are trying to do as those list override each other each iteration... Try to create a [mre] not dependent of the spotify api as some of us are not familiar with it (and it is not really the core of your question...)

Comment: That makes more sense indeed, thanks. That still leaves me with the problem that I have to initalize 12 lists for all the features, retrieve the values 12 times and add to a list 12 times. still seems alot of code duplication to me

Comment: It would be helpful if you explain what you want your final lists to be like. There might be a better way but (for me personally) it is not clear

Comment: @Tomerikoo I want seperate lists. eg lets say we have 2 tracks. t1: {"danceability":0.7, "energy":0.6} and t2: {"danceability":0.2,"energy":0.4}. I want two lists. danceability_list = [0.7,0.2] and energy_list=[0.6,0.4]. I hope that clarifies my question

Comment: Yes indeed except that I think you meant `dance_list = [0.7, 0.2]` right? Anyway now that I understand, I believe the answer by Ken is exactly what you need

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of having multiple lists, you could just have a dictionary.

```
from collections import defaultdict

attribute_lists = defaultdict(list)
for item in track_response:
    for attr in ('energy', 'loudness', 'tempo'):
        attribute_lists[attr].append(item[attr])
```

Comment: This code is just begging to use `defaultdict` can't you hear it? :)

Comment: This makes much more sense. Thank you very much

Comment: Would `defaultDict` work to modify in place like that?

Comment: Another small comment: to make this compact and general, the loop can simply be `for attr in item` or better yet `for attr, value in item.items():` and then `append(value)`

Comment: `for attr in item` assumes you want to collect all attributes. I wasn't assuming that...

Comment: Yeah the default dict should work, about the attributes I guess you are right, depends on what OP needs to take from the item

Comment: `attribute_lists = defaultdict(list)` achieves the same thing as `attribute_lists = defaultdict(lambda: [])` and is more understandable/direct wrt intent. The first arg needs to be a _callable_ and that's what _`list`_ is; so is a lambda.

Comment: Two months into learning python. I did not know the possiblities of defaultdict. Thanks guys cheers